# Discord RPG Bot display ids for each player in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord

I'm trying to learn javascript and how to use the developer api provided by discord.

I do believe everything I want so far is working except I wanted to create a system like how a database works. Where each player in the table has a unique id key. I'm not sure if this is possible without using a db.

[Index.js]

```
/* Discord API Information */
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const token = '';
const Game = require('./game.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

let playersName = []; // tracks each player that joins
let currPlayers = 0; //tracker for total players online
let INIT_GAME;
let userJoined = false;
let inBattle = false;

client.on('message', (msg) => {
    if(msg.content === '!join'){

        // Prevents multiple instances of the same person from joining
        for(var x = 0; x < playersName.length; x++){
            if(playersName[x]===msg.author.username){
                return playersName[x];
            }
        }

        currPlayers++;
        userJoined = true;
        playersName.push(msg.author.username);

        //My attempt at having the question im asking
        function convertToID(arr, width) {
            return arr.reduce(function (rows, key, index) {
              return (index % width == 0 ? rows.push([key])
                : rows[rows.length-1].push(key)) && rows;
            }, []);
          }

        console.log(convertToID(playersName,1)); /* Tracks players by ID in developer tools */

        INIT_GAME = new Game(playersName, client, 'bot-testing', currPlayers);
        let myRet = INIT_GAME.startGame();

        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle("Welcome To Era Online")
        .setColor(0xFF0000)
        .addField(`${msg.author.username} has Joined`, myRet);
        msg.channel.send(embed);
        msg.channel.send(`${msg.author} has joined the game.`);
        return;
    }

    if(userJoined == true){
        if(msg.content === '!fight' && (!inBattle)){
            let grabCurrPlayer = msg.author.username;
            msg.channel.send(`${INIT_GAME.initBattle(grabCurrPlayer)}`);
        }

        else if(msg.content === '!leave'){
            let tempLeave = msg.author.username;

            for(var y = 0; y < playersName.length; y++){
                if(playersName[y] == msg.author.username){
                    playersName[y] = [`${playersName[y]} was previously ID: ` + [y]];
                    currPlayers--;
                }
            }
            msg.channel.send([`${tempLeave} has left the server.`]);
            userJoined = false;
        }

        else if(msg.content === '!newgame'){
            msg.channel.send(INIT_GAME.newGame());
        }

        /* Simply checks the bonus damage. command for developer*/
        else if(msg.content === '!bonus'){
            msg.channel.send(INIT_GAME.bonusAttack());
        }  
    }

    /* checks whose currently online. command for developer*/
    if(msg.content === '!online'){
        msg.channel.send(INIT_GAME.getOnline());
    }

});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is now connected');
});

client.login(token);
```

[game.js]

```
class Game {
    constructor(player, client, channelName='bot-testing', playersOnline){
         this.client = client;
         this.channelName = channelName;
         this.currentPlayer = player;   
         this.playersOnline = [];
         this.hitpoints = 120;
         this.damage = '';
         this.chance = 3;
         this.inBattle = false;
         this.online = playersOnline;

        this.monster = [{
            hp: Math.floor(Math.random() * 200),
            temphp: 0,
            damage: 10
        }];
    };

    /* main menu information, players online */
    startGame(){
            for(var x = 0; x < this.currentPlayer.length; x++){
                this.playersOnline.push(this.currentPlayer[x]);
                if(this.playersOnline[x] === this.currentPlayer[x]){
                    return [`Players Online: ${this.online}\n`];
            }
         }
    }

    /* Battle system */
    initBattle(currPlayer){
        this.inBattle = true;
        let npcHP = this.monster[0].hp;
        let numberOfAttacks = 0;
        let totalDamage=0, totalBonusDamage=0;

        while( this.monster[0].hp > 0 ){
            let playerDamage = Math.floor(Math.random() * (npcHP / 4));  
            if(this.bonusAttack() === 2){
                console.log(`Bonus Attack: ${this.bonusAttack()}`);
                console.log(`Regular damage without bonus attack: ${playerDamage}`);
                playerDamage = playerDamage + 2; 
            }
            this.monster[0].hp -= playerDamage;
            this.hitpoints -= this.monster[0].damage;

            console.log('Monster: ' + this.monster[0].hp);
            console.log('Player: ' + this.hitpoints);
            console.log(`${currPlayer} has attacked for ${playerDamage}`);
            console.log(`NPC health: ${this.monster[0].hp}`);   

            if(this.hitpoints <= 0){
                return [`You lost the battle.`];
            }

            this.inBattle = false;
            numberOfAttacks++; 
            totalDamage += playerDamage;
            totalBonusDamage = playerDamage + this.bonusAttack();    
        }
        if(this.monster[0].hp <= 0 && this.inBattle !== true){
            let maxDamage = totalDamage + totalBonusDamage; 
            return [`${currPlayer} has attacked ${numberOfAttacks} times dealing ${totalDamage} + (${totalBonusDamage}) bonus damage for a total of ${maxDamage} damage. The monster is dead.\n
            Your Health: ${this.hitpoints}`];
        } 
        else{
            this.newGame();
            return [`You rejuvenated your hitpoints and are ready for battle. \nType !fight again to start a new battle!`];
        }
    }

    /* bonus attack damage [ 1 in 3 chance ] */
    bonusAttack(bonusDamage){
        let chance = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        return chance === 2 ? bonusDamage = 2 : false;
    }

    /* displays players currently online */
    getOnline(){
        console.log(this.currentPlayer);
        return this.currentPlayer;

    }

    /* refresh stats */
    newGame(){
        this.monster[0].hp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
        this.hitpoints = 150;
    }
}

module.exports = Game;
```

[My Question]

The only real important part within those 2 files is in index.js at the line that speaks about when a player leaves. So !leave.

I had a problem where one player typed !leave, both people would leave. That is the solution I used to fix it.

I could not get it to empty the array for ONLY the person who typed the command.

Example:

Person A types !join

Players online = [PlayerA]

Person B types !join

Players online = [PlayerA, PlayerB]

Player A types !leave

Players online = [[], PlayerB]]

It would always insert a empty array in the spot.  So what I did was just fill that spot with the users previous name and their array id.

1. What I want is so that it completely deletes the person from the array AND removes that empty spot.
2. I would also like to know if it's possible that every time someone types !join, I would be able to insert them into an new array that is multidimensional and has the id for each player so that when I type !online, it would display

[[0, PlayerA], [1, PlayerB]] . Like a database where I can always see their index if needed.

What I have so far:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1gGn.png

It only tracks the last index after they leave. How do I make it display the current index of the players online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use findIndex() to find the position of the name in your array. Then use the splice() method to remove a value from your array. You don't need to use that for loop, as findIndex will run a similar loop.

```
var playerIndex = playersName.findIndex(function(index) {
  return index === tempLeave
})
playersName.splice(playerIndex, 1)
```

After reading the second part of your question though, I think you should be creating objects inside of your array. An example would be:

```
[
  {
   playerName: "Foo",
   id: indexNumber,
   isOnline: true
  },
 {
  playerName: "Bar",
  id: indexNumber,
  isOnline: true
 }
]
```

When someone joins, you check if their name is already assigned to an object (you can use findIndex again here). If not you create a new player, else you will change the players isOnline attribute to true. I'm sure this is the best way to go about storing user info, but it might work for you.

Comment: I just get an error when I try to use the code that you provided. splice is not defined

Comment: Ah sorry you have to add the array in front of splice, playersName.splice(playerIndex, 1)